# StackExchange.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect & StackExchange.ConnectionMultiplexer.GetServer when using multiple connections?

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

If you have multiple connections in

```
ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(host1, host2, etc.)
```

and

```
StackExchange.ConnectionMultiplexer.GetServer(...)
```

requires exactly 1 endpoint to get server - how to understand this ? How does this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However you connect, behind the scenes the multiplexer may have knowledge of multiple redis server instances. Usually, the server topology is an implementation detail that isn't useful or necessary to the consumer - which is why it isn't needed for APIs exposed under `GetDatabase()`; the library will worry about how to route commands to servers.

However, sometimes, a consumer wants to use an API that is specific to an individual server endpoint; this is where `GetServer()` comes into play. This could be, for example, to read (or change) individual server configurations (although other APIs exist). In that scenario, you obviously need to tell the library *which node you want to talk to*, which is why this is a required parameter to `GetServer()`. Note that you can use the `GetEndPoints()` API to list the endpoints in play (this is **not** necessarily the same as the endpoints you supplied in `Connect[Async]` - for example, a redis cluster declares the topology via a redis command, usually additional nodes).

If you aren't sure what endpoint you would pass to `GetServer(...)`, then *there's a good chance that you shouldn't be using `GetServer(...)`* - by which I mean: the functionality you're after is *probably* exposed on `GetDatabase(...)` instead - which does not require an endpoint to be specified.

Or perhaps more simply:

- `GetDatabase(...)` exposes the *logical* database constructed within redis
- `GetServer(...)` exposes the *underlying infrastructure* of redis servers that provide that database

Comment: Thx for explanation. I checked my code and the only time where I need `GetServer(...)`, is to make a query about the keys: `IServer.Keys(...)` There is no other way (`GetDatabase(...)`) to query keys right?

Comment: @sabiland yes; despite what it is tempting to think, keys is a server-centric API: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan.html

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing this up! Just another quick question, can I put sentinel host/port to `GetServer(...)` ?

Comment: @sabiland are you actually talking to a sentinel instance *as sentinel* (not as a gateway to redis) at the time? if so.... maybe, I haven't tried; if not: no

Comment: We are setting up Sentinels on staging today. Will try all variants with `GetServer(...)`